# Why does the margin of a <p> effect the positioning of the containing div?

Tags: css

I've just come across a CSS issue that I've resolved, but I'd like to know why it happened in the first place or if it is an example of some common CSS behaviour or 'gotcha' I should know about.

Basically, if I did not set the margin of a `<p>` tag to `0px`, I needed to compensate by adding a negative top margin to the containing div (or else there was a 20px space at the top of the div).  I found it odd that the margin of the `<p>` seemed to extend beyond its container.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/4znhV/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="bobble"></div>
<div class="bg">
<p>here is a paragraph la la la la la ...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
margin-top:50px;
}

.tab {
width:39px; 
height:12px; 
background: #ffe4c0; 
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; 
margin-left:14px
}

.bobble {
background:#fffc68;
height:22px;
width:22px;
float:right;
border-radius:12px; 
border: 1px solid #f4f1e4;
margin-top:-8px;
margin-right:-4px;   
}

.bg {
background: #F5F3EA; 
min-height: 93px; 
border-radius: 3px; 
width: 100%;
/* margin-top: -20px; this is required if "margin:0px" is not set on <p> */
}

p {
color: #909090; 
padding: 20px; 
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0px; /* why is this required? */
}
```

Comment: going by your current markup...its because you have added `padding: 20px;` in `p`...you need to compensate in parent `div`!!

Comment: Just a little [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/vb4xd/) to what @NoobEditor was saying.

Comment: @Ruddy : always a help!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to what is called collapsing margins. According to the [Box Model Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)...

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> - both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same    block formatting context
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them (Note that certain zero-height line boxes (see 9.4.2) are ignored for
>     this purpose.)
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   1. **top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child**
>   2. bottom margin of box and top margin of its next in-flow following sibling
>   3. bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has 'auto' computed height
>   4. top and bottom margins of a box that does not establish a new block formatting context and that has zero computed 'min-height', zero
>        or 'auto' computed 'height', and no in-flow children

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well you want paragraph to expand the container right? This can be done by adding

```
position:absolute;
```

to the parent div of

and:

```
position:relative;
```

to paragraph.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jG75/

Hope i helped.

Comment: i think when you give position:absolute; scroll come.

Answer (score 0):

css inheritance

margin for paragraph was not set so it was inherited from parent container
http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-inheritance-cascade/

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4znhV/7/)**

**css**

```
    .container {
margin-top:50px;
}

.tab {
width:39px; 
height:12px; 
background: #ffe4c0; 
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; 
margin-left:14px
}

.bobble {
background:#fffc68;
height:22px;
width:22px;
float:right;
border-radius:12px; 
border: 1px solid #f4f1e4;
margin-top:-8px;
margin-right:-4px;   
}

.bg {
background: #F5F3EA; 

border-radius: 3px; 
width: 100%;
    position:relative;
/* margin-top: -20px; this is required if "margin:0px" is not set on <p> */
}

p {
color: #909090; 
padding: 20px; 
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0px; /* why is this required? */


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the browser has default style! if you don't reset the default css, they will act differently! for example p will have 20px margin-top and margin-bottom in chrome while 15px margin-top margin-bottom in ie!

usually if you want want different version and platform browser looks the same, you may have a reset css to remove all the different acts in the browser!
if you want compatible with IE8 and IE8-bellow, you may want this css http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/,other wise you just need a normalize css to make a small hack!

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/